# mysql error messages explanation

Tags: mysql

I've just installed Mysql on Ubuntu 10.4 LTS  and unfortunately I've been experiencing serious problems.

Using the terminal I gain root access (through the commands:sudo su) and I type :

```
mysql
```

immediately I get this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Then  I type:

```
mysqladmin -u root fist_p second_p_151
```

and I get:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed

error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

I also get errors whenever I want to import a sql file.

Comment: Try: `mysql -u root -p` and then enter the password in the console.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and enter password when required.

Comment: @Mauro: did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes I did thanks a lot ..I still have a few more questions..I do have problems importing a sql file

Comment: @Mauro: accept the answer and ask another question to SO. Take a look to other question: I'm sure you can find the answer there...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Server has its own users, passwords and permissions. You simply can't log into MySQL using your regular Linux users, even if they have the same name (such as `root`). Thus doing `sudo su` serves no purpose.

Have a look at the [-u](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_user) and [-p](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password) parameters in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html).